# What does antithetic in R fOptions' MonteCarloOption simulator do?

Tags: r

The manual says this without too much detail:

Usage:

```
 MonteCarloOption(delta.t, pathLength, mcSteps, mcLoops, init = TRUE, 
     innovations.gen, path.gen, payoff.calc, antithetic = TRUE, 
     standardization = FALSE, trace = TRUE, ...)
```

antithetic: a logical flag, should antithetic variates be used?  By
          default TRUE.

What if turn it to FALSE?

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antithetic_variates ...

Comment: thanks for the link. If a Sobol sequence is used for innovation, this antithetic parameter is still set to TRUE?

Comment: Have you looked at the source by typing `MonteCarloOption`? It's not very long or complicated ...

Comment: great idea ... thx